# Alternate shell behaving strangely

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, sudosh

I set up my default shell on ubuntu to be sudosh2 instead of the default /bin/bash.

Now when I ssh into the account, I get some presumably bare-bones shell behavior (only `$` prompt, arrow keys result in `^[[D`, etc.)

What does that mean, and how do I get a normal bash shell to load, without having to manually start /bin/bash every time I ssh in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the `/bin/sh` shell, which never supported arrow keys or other such features in the first place. Its default prompt is `$`.

Edit the "`default shell`" parameter in `/etc/sudosh2.conf` to launch *bash* instead.